# How to remove the dark line at the start of Fireworks image fade gradents?

Tags: gradient, adobe-fireworks

In Fireworks I need the images I work with to fade to white on the left hand edge. Unfortunately I can't seem to get fireworks to behave the way I want it to.

First off, as seen in the image, there is a vertical darker line (compared to the rest of the image) at the start of the gradient. Secondly I can't seem to make it a smooth gradient from the image to transparent with it always fading more at the start or end of the gradient.

My process is as follows.

1. On a white box I have a linear gradient that has both White (#FFF) to Black (#000) and a transparently gradient with 100% to 0% (or at 50% as it worked better for the image below). I found that having ether one or the other doesn't work as well
2. Grab an image I want the effect applied too and 'Paste inside' the white box.
3. Unlink the layers and select 'Mask: Grayscale appearance' on the image.

[image: A bad gradient]

So my questions are how do I remove the dark line at the start of the gradient and how do I make it smooth?

Also I know that you can do this in Photoshop but I prefer to use Fireworks so no 'use Photoshop' answers please.

Comment: I can see no dark line but you need a gradient from white 100% to white 0%